# Fetching property which have whitespaces in key from consul

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, consul-kv

How we can fetch the property which has whitespaces in the key from the consul to Spring Boot application?

I am trying to fetch properties that have white spaces in the key and try to store them in a map in Spring Boot application but the whitespaces are ignored in the result.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are trying to do with an example?